# google.script.host.close is not a function / self-closing popup

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

Trying to figure out an annoyance.  I have 2 separate web apps in Google Apps Script (one runs as the user, one runs as the script owner. They don't actually talk to each other - other than script 1 opens a popup with a pre-formatted URL with the correct parameters etc.)

Web App 1 opens Web App 2 in a popup. Web App 2 should ideally be able to close itself, but I can't seem to figure out how.  I've tried `open(location, '_self').close();` as well as `google.script.host.close();`

My current setup is below:

Web App 1 Client-Side (No issues)

```
function common_token_ready(instructionsObject){   
  var url = instructionsObject.pickerURL;   
  window.open(url,"_blank","height=720,width=1280"); 
}
```

Web App 2 Client Side (Works other than being unable to close itself)

```
function save_success_handler(response){
  document.getElementById("main").innerHTML = "Please close this window to continue.";
  google.script.host.close();
}
```

I get a TypeError google.script.host.close is not a function

Any ideas?

Comment: I think google.script.host.close() only closes dialog created with the UI Class and it only works on dialogs not web  apps.

Comment: Did you find a way to make it work?